# MySql Insert doesn't work when the website deployed on the host!

Tags: php, mysql, deployment, insert, xampp

I'm using XAPP under windows and my website just working well!

when I deployed it on the host server, it seems to be working normally, but the insert requests to MySql doesn't have any effect, nothing is changing on the database!

Does anyone had this issue before? is there any configuration in MySql to make it accept insert requests? or simply whats the best way to make it work!

[**EDIT**]

**I use PhpMyAdmin**, I have two tables **members** and **notifications**, I wanna configure permissions so I can Insert into the **notifications** table, any hint please?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

check the permissions on the database server for the username and password that you are using. It can also be restricted by IP address, among others.

Comment: I use PhpMyAdmin, can I use it to configure permission settings? thanx

Comment: You sure can, I use it myself.  It makes it so much easier.

Comment: It will almost walk your through the steps from the 'Privileges' link/tab on the front page of PhpMyAdmin

Comment: that's the problem, in the host, I can just access to my database part in PhpMyAdmin, I have no access to the users link! is there an SQL query that may do that?

Comment: No.  You do not yourself have permission to alter the permissions. If you can select & alter the tables and their contents, then double check you are using the same username/password in the code, otherwise talk to the DB admin

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the administrator can set read-only privileges for a user or for a specific table.
Check out the "[grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)" command for more information.

Comment: I use PhpMyAdmin, can I use it to configure permission settings? thanx

Comment: Not sure there's a tool directly but you still have the sql command prompt. If you are not sure about this you should just send an email to your host tech service, I'm sure they will help you out (it may even happen you don't have sufficent privileges to do it on your own).

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful if you could find out the error message that MySQL is returning. check your web server log files. if you are using some shared hosting plan, there should be an option in your host control panel to see the web server log files. PHP is configured in most places so that error messages are stored in web server log files. find out what is actually happening there. it could be permissions most likely.